# Send POST request with csv file without storing the file

Tags: php, csv, curl

Is it possible to send a POST request (using `curl`) with a CSV file (as POST parameter) without saving this file on disk?

I made a CSV file from an array using the PHP function `fputcsv`

Comment: Yes sure. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Now I save before sending (use curl) the file to disk. But I'm looking for a way not to do it

Comment: I found one way: "...Simply use it when it is stored in the tmp folder.

PHP will automagically delete it for you when your script ends." But it's not quite what I was looking for